# Decrypt WhatsApp backup on Google Drive

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

I have lost my phone number and there is no way I can get back the same number from the operator. I want to restore my WhatsApp chats which were safely backed up on Google Drive. I can't arrange the same phone number to receive backup on my Android device because the number has been allotted to someone else.

Can anyone help to decrypt those backups from Google Drive?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/I-lost-my-mobile-How-can-I-recover-my-WhatsApp-messages

Comment: Or call the person to whom your number is allotted to and ask them of they can allow you to just retrieve your back up from WhatsApp,  then you can easily switch numbers.

Comment: Related: [How do I access to my WhatsApp backup in Google Drive?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209173/44325)

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp Backups are stored in your google Drive account, but **you cannot download/read those files** as they are encrypted. From google Drive, you can only *delete* them (as shown in picture) or *remove them from GDrive account*.

[image]

Even if you're logged with the Google account where the backup is stored, **you cannot restore it if you are not using the same phone number that was used to create the backup.** ([more info here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20887921/?category=5245251))

I think the best way to find a solution is [contact the Whatsapp support](http://mailto:support@whatsapp.com) directly. There is no way to download your backup from gdrive right now.