# How do I access to my WhatsApp backup in Google Drive?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

My phone was stolen and I was unable to reclaim my number from my telco. Therefore, I'm not able to log in to WhatsApp with my stolen number. There are very important messages and contacts that I have to retrieve, and I knew that the backups were in Google Drive, but I can't locate the backup file.

Any help that I can retrieve my chat history from Google Drive?

Comment: Does simply trying whatsapp on a different phone not work? Login to the same Google account on the other phone and see if the chats download.

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial Products that claim that they are able to extract Whatsapp backups from Google Drive:

### [Elcomsoft Explorer for WhatsApp](https://www.elcomsoft.com/exwa.html)

[Extract and Decrypt Android WhatsApp Backups from Google Account](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/01/extract-and-decrypt-whatsapp-backups-from-google/)