# WhatsApp chat backup in Android backup on Google Drive

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

I recently broke my Google Pixel 3a and now I got a new phone (Samsung Galaxy S9, running on the same Android version, Android 10). Now I would like to restore my WhatsApp chats from my old phone. I could not manage to retrieve the local chat backup from my Pixel phone and I did not store any WhatsApp backups on Google Drive. However, I have a phone backup called 'backup of Pixel 3a' in my Google Drive. I was able to restore that backup on my new phone. As it seems, that backup contains my local settings, call log and which apps I installed on my previous phone. Apparently, some app data is also included in this backup.

Now my question is: Is there any way to retrieve my WhatsApp chats from this phone backup on Google Drive?

Comment: See this https://mobiletrans.wondershare.com/whatsapp/read-whatsapp-backup-from-google-drive-on-pc.html

Comment: Note that according to the manifest file, WhatsApp disables system backup, so it's not included on the phone's Drive backup.

Comment: Related: [How do I access to my WhatsApp backup in Google Drive?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209173/44325)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to retrieve my WhatsApp chats from this phone backup on Google Drive?

I don't quite understand, if you want to backup from Google Drive, if it's been set up, then it should be automatic. Check your google drive, top left menu, backups, if there exists a whatsapp file. If not, you don't have a backup in GD.

What I would probably do is to try and access the phone through ADB (if possible) repair the phone/screen, copy local files over, deactivate google drive backup, and just restore from local backup.