# Possible to make a copy of WhatsApp backup stored in Google Drive?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-backup

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S9. When my WhatsApp is regularly backed up to my Google Drive, the old one is deleted. I want to keep a copy of the old one, that was backed up to Google Drive.

How can I do it? Or you can tell me how to make a copy to the PC if you know it too.

Comment: Possible dupe: [How do I access my WhatsApp backup in Google Drive?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209173/44325)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access to my Whatsapp backup in Google Drive?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209173/how-do-i-access-to-my-whatsapp-backup-in-google-drive)

Comment: No. I know how to access it. I was asking how to make a copy. It seems that I must install third party stuff. I do not do that unless I definitely know that it is a trusted source in every way. They probably are but I do not have time to confirm. So I will simply use another google account to backup . This way the old one in the first google account will remain.