# How do I back up the WhatsApp backup that is on Google Drive?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

How do I back up the WhatsApp backup that is on Google Drive?

If I go to WhatsApp - Settings - Chats - Chat backup, it tells me the Google account that my backup is at and the size.

[image]

And if I go to https://drive.google.com/drive/backups, then I can see the backup there.

[image]

Google Drive doesn't even tell me the size of the backup! But it tells me the date or time of it which verifies with what the WhatsApp app shows.

How can I copy it off?

I tried Google Takeout  picking just Google Drive. But that just gives a 9MB file. So it didn't include it.

Comment: added note- It does seem a bit vulnerable to me because if some things go wrong eg phone breaks and new phone doesn't load old messages, and decides to do a backup then who knows maybe it could overwrite that one.(not tested yet) There's still a question of, even if I did backup the backup, whether whatsapp would even be able to read the backup or the backup or whether any third party app could.. but anyhow. Also.. I have some ideas maybe  I can copy it off the phone.. though id have to see if I can then reload it. Anyhow.

Comment: BTW I did have issue in past where a phone wouldn't load backup, (Afte it said something about "last chance"),.   which i resolved by removing a local file from the phone then it loaded. But  I want to backup the backup so the situation is a little bit less insecure!

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How do I access to my WhatsApp backup in Google Drive?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209173/44325)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user interface on google drive do not allow you to do this. And they will [delete it](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/211762088?hl=en&msgid=213113935) after 5 month. So if you plan to not to use your whatsapp for a while you'd better to backup your local backup.

- `whatsapp data takeout` does not contain chat history
- `google data takeout` [does not](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/211762088?hl=en&msgid=213113935) include any backup data
- `google drive` [does not allow](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/211762088?hl=en&msgid=213113935) you to copy/download backup data
- you cannot import/restore chats from different account (when you changed your phone number)
- whatsapp will delete your backup immediately if you close your account or uninstall all instance of whatsapp
- google drive will delete your backup immediately if you close or unlink your google account.

But, there are [FOSS tools](https://github.com/limontec/WhatsApp-GDrive-Downloader) for forensic analysis allow you to extract from google driver